# Powerapps Form control, highlight edited data field

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

```
If(SharePointForm1.Mode=FormMode.Edit && ThisItem.'User'.Value <> DataCardValue3.Selected.Value,Red,blue)
```

I am in the process of highlighting the field by changing border color in the form when user edit/change the field value on the edit form Powerapps.

I use above conditional formula for field which works fine for textbox field and for single select dropdown/combobox field but for multi select field I get "Invalid argument type" error in "Not equal to (<>)" symbol

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

This error usually happens when the data types of both don't match. First, check if **ThisItem.'User'.Value** and **DataCardValue3.Selected.Value** has the same data type. And I doubt why you have used **'** with **ThisItem.'User'.Value**.